# Convert a list of a custom class to an object array

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I have a list of a custom class, which contains various variables of type double, string, etc.

In order to return this to excel with Excel DNA, I need to convert the list to `object[,]`.

Here is what I did, but is there a better way? If I add another variable I need to remember to redo the number of columns, etc.

```
List<customclass> BMrep = somefunction();
var retdata = new object[BMrep.Count,22];

for (int i = 0; i < BMrep.Count; i++)
{
    retdata[i, 0] = BMrep[i].product_code;
    retdata[i, 1] = BMrep[i].RG;
    ...
}

return retdata;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use reflection to get the properties:

```
var properties = typeof(customclass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                          BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

List<customclass> BMrep = somefunction();
var retdata = new object[BMrep.Count, properties.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < BMrep.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < properties.Count; j++)
    {
        retdata[i, j] = properties[j].GetValue(BMrep[i], null);
    }
}

return retdata;
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this ensure that the fiels of custom class come in the same order?

Comment: @nik no it does not. [The order is not guaranteed at all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx), so you should order it somehow. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: thats what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Tim S. gave you a pretty solid answer.

However, if those `various variables` you mentioned are fields and not properties, it won't work. You could just change it to `GetFields` instead of `GetProperties` (and GetValue wouldn't need the second `null` parameter)

Here's another example which would work with fields (using linq, a bit shorter):

```
class A
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    public string Field3;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A myA = new A() { Field1 = "rofl", Field2 = "lol", Field3 = "omg" };
    var obj = (from prop in typeof(A).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                select prop.GetValue(myA)).ToArray();

    Debug.Assert(obj[0] == "rofl");
    Debug.Assert(obj[1] == "lol");
    Debug.Assert(obj[2] == "omg");
}
```

If you'd like it to work with properties, just replace the linq with this:

```
var obj2 = (from prop in typeof(A).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            select prop.GetValue(myA,null)).ToArray();
```

I typed `var` to be short but `obj` and `obj2` are of type `Object[]`

**EDIT:**

As specified by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order.

So if you want to keep the order, you could create an `Attribute` on the field/property which could keep this information. See below:

```
class OrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; private set; }

    public OrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        this.Order = order;
    }
}

class A
{
    public string FieldWithoutOrder;
    [Order(3)] public string Field1;
    [Order(2)] public string Field2;
    [Order(1)] public string Field3;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A myA = new A() { Field1 = "rofl", Field2 = "lol", Field3 = "omg", FieldWithoutOrder = "anarchy" };
    var obj = (from prop in typeof(A).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               orderby prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrderAttribute),true).Select(att=>((OrderAttribute)att).Order).DefaultIfEmpty(Int32.MaxValue).First()
               select prop.GetValue(myA)
                ).ToArray();

    var obj2 = (from prop in typeof(A).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               select prop.GetValue(myA,null)).ToArray();

    Debug.Assert(obj[0] == "omg"); //Field3
    Debug.Assert(obj[1] == "lol"); //Field2
    Debug.Assert(obj[2] == "rofl"); //Field1
    Debug.Assert(obj[3] == "anarchy"); //FieldWithoutOrder
}
```

The `DefaultIfEmpty` specifies a value in case the field doesn't have the `Order` Attribute.

This way it'll be easy for you to maintain (if you need to change the order of the fields, just change in the attribute)

I didn't do it for `obj2` but you can paste the same `orderby` statement and it'll work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! same question as to Tim. I heard that if you use reflection you cannot be sure that the fields come in the same order every time, but obviously this matters here as I need to fill this to excel in the right order...